# How can I measure how much memory consume my java application

Tags: java, memory-management

It is very important to know that **how much memory** can consume my **java application** e.g. how much **RAM** and **CPU** speed.

Comment: Hi please refer this link,hope your doubt will clear.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/37916136/9502833

Comment: Why ROM ? Could you explain any scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the memory usages and also the number of threads used for your application by profilers.

There are many profilers are available, Below I have given few famous profilers which have been used across.

- [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)
- [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/)
- [Java VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)
- Eclipse profiler -
  [Memory Analyzer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/memory-analyzer-0) | [JVM Monitor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jvm-monitor)
- [Netbeans Profiler](https://profiler.netbeans.org/)