# How to upload file to azure blob storage directly from spring boot application, without taking file in to in-memory (Buffer memory)

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

I have spring boot application which will upload zip file (size > 250MB) to azure blob storage, if file is not directly uploaded to azure then it will use in-memory space which might lead to shortage of memory size in case of multiple requests. So, please give me some reference or code snippet to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to directly upload a file to Azure blob, please refer to the following steps

1. SDK

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.6.0</version>
        </dependency
```

2. Code

```
@PostMapping(path = "/upload")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String constr="";


        BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(constr)
                .containerName("upload")
                .buildClient();


        BlobClient blob=container.getBlobClient(file.getOriginalFilename());

        blob.upload(file.getInputStream(),file.getSize(),true);


        return "ok";
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this code will wait until full file is received by mutilpartfile(takes file in to local memory), I just want to stream file directly to azure.

Comment: @brijeshPatil The method will read and upload in chunks. It does not load all buffers in memory  then upload to Azure. For more details, please refer to  https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9bLt.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KlUS.png

Comment: ok thanks for the help, really appreciated

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't load file in to buffer memory because when I test it shows it using 5MB for 5MB file and 1MB for 1MB file. I'm calculating memory using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916136/how-to-calculate-memory-usage-of-a-java-program) at beginning of request method and at the end of the method

Comment: @brijeshPatil If you want to upload file to Azure in your client application, we must use the memory because we need to use some space to save the data from the input stream when you upload data to the blob server. We just can control how may memoery we use when we call the method.